# php: og: meta for facebook can't read variables

Tags: php, variables, facebook-opengraph

Is one week tht i stayup untill the 2 of the night to find a solution, without result.

I want to share the article of my websIte (normal, no WP or other CMS) On facebook, but when I press Share button, I can't see the title of the article and the description. In the title instead appear my domain (mydomainname.xxxx), while the description is completely empty. Also the facebook debugger is not of some help. I tried really everything, also to create a file with only the of meta, where pass variable through the $_POST/$_GET method. Useless to say that didn't work too... Maybe i must force it and use the API, but I did not understand how that works.  Thanks in advance.

Anyway the interested code is:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . 

"://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 



?>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<?Php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include("script/configurazione.php");
include("script/funzioni.php");

session_start();
$lingua = $_SESSION['lingua'];
$idPubblicazione=$_GET["idpubblicazione"];



switch ($lingua) {
    case "italiano":
        break;
    case "inglese":
        break;
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  if ($ip !='94.189.161.160'){
  $ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $file = fopen("provenienze.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,"\n".$ip);
    fputs ($file, " ".$ref);
    fclose($file);
    }
 //SET ERROR REPORTING
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);
$deny = array("118.127.15.83", "60.191.38.77, 220.156.166.55, 117.242.36.35, 89.254.221.5, 62.182.88.205, 31.162.139.228, 121.58.251.170");
foreach ($deny as $denyip) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $denyip)===0) {
    header("location: http://www.google.com/");
    exit();
  } 
}

        //questo serve per trovare l'id quando inizia la sessione e non c'è scelta
            if ($idPubblicazione == '' ){ 


$sql = ("SELECT * FROM news order by data ");
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $id = sprintf( $row["id"]);
            $idPubblicazione=$id;}
        //-------------------------------

?>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/li-scroller.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js'></script>


<?php 

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM news where id = '$idPubblicazione'");

    $result = $connessione->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();}

        $sdata = sprintf( $row["data"]); 
        $sdata = date("y/m/d", strtotime($sdata));
        $spathtxt=sprintf( $row["pathtxt"]); 
        $sfoto=sprintf( $row["foto"]); 
        $spathfoto=sprintf( $row["pathimg"]); 
        $foto=$spathfoto.$sfoto;


        switch ($lingua) {

    case "italiano":
    $pubblicazioni='Lista Pubblicazioni';
    $mnews='Lista News';
    $stitolo = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["titolo"])); 
    $sargomento = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["argomento"]));
    $sfileita = sprintf( $row["fileita"]);
    $sfileita= str_replace(".txt", "",$sfileita);
    $files=$spathtxt.$sfileita;
        break;
    case "inglese":
    $pubblicazioni='Pubblication List';
    $mnews='News List';
    $stitolo = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["titoloing"])); 
    $sargomento = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["argomentoing"]));
    $sfileing = sprintf( $row["fileing"]);
    $sfileing= str_replace(".txt", "",$sfileing);
    $files=$spathtxt.$sfileing;
        break;
    case "spagnolo":
    $pubblicazioni='Lista de Publicaciones';
    $mnews='Lista News';
    $stitolo = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["titolospa"])); 
    $sargomento = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["argomentospa"]));
    $sfilespa = sprintf( $row["filespa"]);
    $sfilespa= str_replace(".txt", "",$sfilespa);
    $files=$spathtxt.$sfilespa;
        break;  
    case "tedesco":
    $pubblicazioni='Veröffentlichungen Liste';
    $mnews='News Liste';
    $stitolo = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["titoloted"])); 
    $sargomento = sprintf( str_replace("%", "%%",$row["argomentoted"]));
    $sfileted = sprintf( $row["fileted"]);
    $sfileted= str_replace(".txt", "",$sfileted);
    $files=$spathtxt.$sfileted;
        break;      

}
        $testo = leggifile($files);
        $testo= str_replace("%", "%%",$testo);
        $testo= str_replace("!*", "<strong>",$testo);
        $testo= str_replace("*!", "</strong>",$testo);
        $testo = preg_replace(
  '#((https?|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i',
  "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4",$testo
);

?>



<meta property="fb:app_id" content="myappid" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo ($stitolo); ?>" >
<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo ($sargomento); ?>" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://mysite/img/logo148-01.png" />



</head>
```

Comment: Which parts of this code are really relevant? If the description is missing, maybe the `og:description` field is empty?

Comment: No, sorry I forgot to say that if I look on the generated webpage source code with any browser everything is filled correctly. So it seems a problem of FB. If can help even more, the articles is inside an iframe.